# What's the alternative of using release phase on Heroku?

Tags: docker, heroku

Can we run migrations using for example docker `entrypoint.sh` file and avoid using heroku specific "release phase"? If not, how can we achieve auto-run migrations?

Comment: You can run them manually, but I don't think that's what you want. Why would you want to avoid Heroku's release phase? What's wrong with it?

Comment: I thought one of the benefits of using Docker is to avoid dependency to a specific environment, like Heroku

Comment: I disagree that that's the whole purpose of Docker, but this isn't really a dependency. At least, not in the runtime sense. It's part of _deployment_. This can be accomplished by running the command manually, or via Heroku's release phase, or as part of your CI / CD pipeline, or whatever else makes sense for you. Running migrations via your `Dockerfile` or similar doesn't make much sense IMO since it needs to happen once for your logical database, not once per application node.

Comment: Just to add, Heroku will restart your dynos every 24 hours, so having migrations run in `entrypoint.sh` means your migrations will be run every 24hrs. Everything will probably be fine as your migrations will detect that they have already run but still not really desirable. Running migrations in the release command avoids this. Also if you make a config change the release command wont run but in your case your migrations will attempt to run.